# Proving an isomorphism without a defined function

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be the group of nonzero complex numbers under multiplication
and let $N$ be the set of complex numbers of absolute value $1$ (that is,
$a + bi \in N$ if $a^2 + b^2 = 1$). 
Show that $G/N$ is isomorphic to the group of all positive real numbers under multiplication.

**No answer please**

Suppose that the group of real numbers is $\mathbb R$.

I'm a bit confused about proving isomorphism since there isn't any defined function that maps between $G/N$ and $\mathbb R$.

I've tried to approach this by proving that group $G$ is homomorphic to $G/N$, using the the quotient group of $G$ by $N$, $N(x+y)$ for an $X$ and $Y$ in $G/N$ where $X = Nx$ and $Y = Ny$, as the function  $g:G \to G/N$, but now I'm not sure what function is mapping between $G/N$ and $\mathbb R$. I know I need to first prove that $f:G/N\to\mathbb R$ is homomorphic, but how is that possible if $f$ isn't even defined?

Comment: all you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem

Comment: Your function shouldn't map to $\Bbb{R}$, which is an additive group, but to $\Bbb{R}^{\times}$, which is a multiplicative group.

Comment: To show that two groups are isomorphic, you should find an isomorphism between them. So you should find or construct an isomorphism between $\Bbb{C}^{\times}/N$ and $\Bbb{R}^{\times}$ yourself. And in stead of trying to find a homomorphism from $\Bbb{C}^{\times}/N$ to $\Bbb{R}^{\times}$, try finding a homomorphism from $\Bbb{C}^{\times}$ to $\Bbb{R}^{\times}$ with kernel $N$. Then the isomorphism theorem will help you.

Comment: And as you state that you are confused, maybe its better that you don't use the first isomorphism theorem, but rather search for a representation system of $\mathbb C^*/N$ and then see if you can construct an isomorphism to $\mathbb R_{\gt 0}$. Intuitively $\mathbb C^*/N$ is the group if you mod out the information of $N$ out of $C^*$.

Comment: Alternatively, in this case drawing a picture also helps; what do the elements of $\Bbb{C}^{\times}/N$, i.e. the cosets of $N$ in $\Bbb{C}^{\times}$, look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove the isomorphism, you have to provide the function $f$ (the one you say is not defined).

Hint: the quotient yields an equivalency between complex numbers that lie in the same circumference (two complex numbers with the same modulus differ only in argument and their quotient is a complex number with modulus $1$ and with that difference as argument). The classes under this equivalency are all circumferences centered at $0$. Which is the natural way of assigning one positive real number to each of this classes?

Answer (score 0):

The comments are there, who knows if they helped you out. Now, you can try the following: define

$$\phi:\Bbb C^*\to\Bbb R^+\;,\;\;\phi\left(|z|e^{it}\right):=|z|$$

Now prove what's needed: it is surjective, what its kernel is, etc. and use the first isomorphism theorem